# How can I change one specific row from a ListView?

Tags: android

I've searched dozens of manuals and tutorials but I haven't managed to do it.

What I need is just change the background / textcolor of a row from a ListView.

It's only one row different from the others but it can be in any position (which I already know) so I just need to know how to acces to the desired row..

I'm sorry if it's been already asked/answered but I haven't find anything that solves my case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same issues and I agree with you, this topic isn't too much explained in the most common android manual.

I explain how I did for draw different type of row, you have to extends an Baseadapter and override :

getItemViewType(position)

getViewTypeCount(position)

getView()

If you have two type of rows you have to return alway 2 in getViewTypeCount(), in the getItemViewType() you have to return the number of view for the element present on your adapter ( an ArrayList tipically.

See this for a complete example : http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

Comment: Thank you, I've finally got to my point! It's working now following more or less the example given.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, since views in a ListView are recycled, if the specific row you're trying to access is not visible, it's not possible to modify it as it doesn't actually exist at that time. Can you be more descriptive on what your actual goal is with this? If it's dependent on the content of the cell, it might be better to code a check into your `getView()` method of your adapter to check the specific view for that content, and color the background if it does contain it.

Comment: My goal is having a playlist with songs and highlight the one that is currently playing.

Comment: I see. I'm unfamiliar with handling the media player in android, but this is my speculation on what I would do: set a variable for the Uri of the currently playing song, then in your getView() method, check if that song's Uri matches that of the currently playing Uri, and then set your color. You may also want to call notifyDataSetChanged() on the listview once a song finishes or is skipped. Someone else might have a better idea, but that's how I would start on it.

Answer (score 1):

main.xml

java file
package webkul.com.todo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class add extends Activity {
    private ListView Lview;

```
private String a[]={"aaa","aaaaafddf","bcvnxc"};
  static ArrayList <String>arlst=new ArrayList<String>();
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }

    });
    Button next1=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    final EditText aa=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtInput);
    //final ArrayList arlst=new ArrayList();
    next1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){

            String a1=aa.getText().toString();
            arlst.add(a1);
            aa.setText("");

            //arlst.add("aa2");
            //Toast.makeText(add.this, "Position=" +a1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Todo.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);



        }

    });


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your ListActivity class, which manages the listview, you will have to override the method onListItemClick - modify the colour here:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id)
{       
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

You can use your own colours stored in your resource file.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to extend the ListAdapter you are currently using. Overriding then getView method to intercept the view that the ListActivity is using to display a visible row.

Maybe something like the following:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
  public MyListAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
      int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
  } 
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    if (v != null && position == 2) {
      v.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }
    return v;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this has also been useful!